# Responsive issues with table-cell

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am looking for a solution on the following page:

The area I am having issues with is the table under "Locations".  When the browser is resized down, I would like each row in the table to break down as follows:

Name of Place

Address

View on Map (button)   Upcoming Demo (button)

The above should also all appear within the green background in a row, if there is one.

```css
.wtb-table {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.wtb-row-one {
 display: table-row;
}
.wtb-row-one .wtb-placename, .wtb-row-one .wtb-address {
 background: #f2f8f2;
}
.wtb-row-two {
 display: table-row;
}
.wtb-placename {
 display: table-cell;
 color: #707070;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 2%;
 text-align: left;
 width: 30%;
}
.wtb-address {
 display: table-cell;
 color: #707070;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 2%;
 width: 30%;
}
.wtb-view-btn {
 display: table-cell;
 background: none;
 width: 15%;
}
.wtb-view-btn div {
 
}
.wtb-view-btn div a {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #007940;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 font-weight: 600;
 border: 2px solid #007940;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.wtb-demo {
 display: table-cell;
 background: none;
 width: 15%;
}
.wtb-demo a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background: #abc13d;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="wtb-table">
 <div class="wtb-row-one">
  <div class="wtb-placename">Name of Place</div>
  <div class="wtb-address">1234 Address St, Ottawa ON</div>
  <div class="wtb-view-btn"><div><a href="#">VIEW ON MAP</a></div></div>
  <div class="wtb-demo"><div><a href="#">UPCOMING DEMO</a></div></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="wtb-row-two">
  <div class="wtb-placename">Name of Place</div>
  <div class="wtb-address">1234 Address St, Ottawa ON</div>
  <div class="wtb-view-btn"><div><a href="#">VIEW ON MAP</a></div></div>
  <div class="wtb-demo">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="wtb-row-one">
  <div class="wtb-placename">Name of Place</div>
  <div class="wtb-address">1234 Address St, Ottawa ON</div>
  <div class="wtb-view-btn"><div><a href="#">VIEW ON MAP</a></div></div>
  <div class="wtb-demo"><div><a href="#">UPCOMING DEMO</a></div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look into media queries

Comment: What specifically are you having issues with? I see your link/buttons breakdown on small browser widths

Comment: @JamesKing Looks like my initial post didn't show the formatting I'm looking for.  When resized down I need each table row to show the content one line at a time.  So "Name of Place" would be the first line, with "Address" as the second line, and then the buttons underneath as the third line.

Comment: Theres actually quite a lot of changes needed to achieve what you want. By default you need all the DIVs invloved in your table to be display: block or inline-block, then only convert them to table-row/cell using media queries. You need to also apply the BG colour to the row div and not the cells

Answer (score 0):

you have a responsible problem with your buttons when you resize the page. Try with this :

```
<div id="test">
<div class="wtb-view-btn"><div><a href="#">VIEW ON MAP</a></div></div>
<div class="wtb-demo"><div><a href="#">UPCOMING DEMO</a></div></div>
</div>

#test {
width: 366px;
}
```

Just adding a div before your div with class "class="wtb-view-btn"" and after div with class "class="wtb-demo""

Add a width to this div.

Comment: This does not achieve what I'm looking for.  I need that table to change so that each text line in a row is on top of each other, with the buttons below them.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/css/

```
   <div class="wtb-table col-md-12">
    <div class="wtb-row-one col-md-4">
        <div class="wtb-placename">Name of Place</div>
        <div class="wtb-address">1234 Address St, Ottawa ON</div>
        <div class="wtb-view-btn"><div><a href="#">VIEW ON MAP</a></div></div>
        <div class="wtb-demo"><div><a href="#">UPCOMING DEMO</a></div></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wtb-row-two col-md-4">
        <div class="wtb-placename">Name of Place</div>
        <div class="wtb-address">1234 Address St, Ottawa ON</div>
        <div class="wtb-view-btn"><div><a href="#">VIEW ON MAP</a></div></div>
        <div class="wtb-demo">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wtb-row-one col-md-4">
        <div class="wtb-placename">Name of Place</div>
        <div class="wtb-address">1234 Address St, Ottawa ON</div>
        <div class="wtb-view-btn"><div><a href="#">VIEW ON MAP</a></div></div>
        <div class="wtb-demo"><div><a href="#">UPCOMING DEMO</a></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```